# Can I post to a facebook applications wall before the user "Likes" the application?

Tags: facebook

I have a mobile application that can successfully authenticate and post to the user and facebook application's wall after the user goes to the web site and "likes" the application.

Is there anyway to have the user "like" the application without requiring them to go to the web site?  Or is there anyway to post to the applications wall without the user "liking" the application?

Answer (score 1):

No, otherwise there would be infinite apps that would spam the hell out of everyone they could find, without the permission of the users being spammed.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain this well.  I have an app that wants to write back to the original app page, not any other users wall.  My user has given the app offline_access and publish_stream permissions.  My goal is to have the app just post status updates to the app, not anyone elses pages.  Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see how this could result in potential for spam.